# Get Windows XP Sound Recorder on Windows 10

Tags: windows-xp, windows-10, audio

Years ago, I used to make easy musical recordings with Sound Recorder because I could record a track, and play it in the background with another window of Sound Recorder open, and then make a track with both a backing and lead.

I was able to use some hex code I found online to restore Windows Photo Viewer, so I don't use to use Windows 10's "Photos." Is there a way to restore the Sound Recorder from XP?

Comment: I think you're software shopping and you'd likely want to check with http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ but check out [Audacity](https://sourceforge.net/projects/audacity/)... **Audacity is a free, easy-to-use, multi-track audio editor and recorder for Windows, Mac OS X, GNU/Linux and other operating systems. Audacity is free software, developed by a group of volunteers and distributed under the GNU General Public License (GPL).**

Comment: true, but it was so easy with the XP one

Answer (score 2):

1. Start up a Windows XP machine and locate the file sndrec32.exe
2. Copy that file to your Windows 10 machine and try to run it. Maybe you need to run it in compatibility mode.

Comment: There is often also an associated DLL, most likely sndred32.dll (speaking from copying the telnet client)

Comment: there's no site where I can download the files?

Comment: @KrissyMichaelsson This seems to work just fine and I grabbed the EXE from my XP virtual machine. You must right-click on it and run as administrator though... I uploaded the file as a ZIP and uploaded it to http://www.filedropper.com/sndrec32 if you want to grab from there and extract from the Zip file.

Comment: @KrissyMichaelsson there is no site because this software is property of Microsoft and redistributing it is illegal,l.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT, thanks! However, even when I right-click and open as admin, whenever I click record after having stopped it, it says "not enough memory to complete this operation..." even tho this computer has more memory than most XP machines ever had loll. Is there a fix?

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT  I ran in compatibility mode and its goin well!